# Is there a way to access grouped columns after groupby()?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm doing a project and there's something I'm curious about **pandas groupby()**. After I grouped columns with **groupby()**. I just want to access **alphabet** column. Can I do it after grouped two columns?

```
macsx = new_dataset.groupby(['alphabet', 'subject'], as_index=False)['maccs']
net = macsx.apply(lambda _df : _df.iloc[0:20]).reset_index(drop=True)

net
```

[My dataset looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWPfn.png)

[This is the output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LaVV.png)

I want the output of my code to look like this:

```
A
A
A
A
.
.
.
Ş
Ş
Ş
```

If explained more clearly after applying the function to the grouped data set I just want to separate columns again. Now **alphabet** column can have 1000 rows like **maccs** column. I am asking if there is a way to do this?

Thank you for now.

Comment: Could you please post a minimal dataframe with a few rows and relevant columns as text along with the expected output so that it is easier to recreate the problem. It is not very clear what you are trying to do

Comment: `I want to access one of grouped columns.` - Not real clear what you are trying to do. Can you add a *fake* DataFrame to your [mre] maybe trhe second example in [Splitting an object into groups](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups) then group it and explain what you want to do?  [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I edited my question hope it will be understandable now. I shared photos but they are displayed as a link.

Comment: There is too much of your code that is outside the scope of what is posted to help. But there are a handful of issues already present, such as the 'dataset' which is being passed to the method.

Comment: @Boskosnitch Thank you. I edited my question again. I reduced code part to my main question.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I can gather, you don't need to be using a groupby, but just sort_values.

instead of;

```
macsx = new_dataset.groupby(['alphabet', 'subject'], as_index=False)['maccs']
```

try;

```
macsx = new_dataset.sort_values(by=['alphabet', 'subject'])['maccs']
```